# SignalR, Silverlight5 and .NET4: Which nuget packages should I use?

Tags: .net-4.0, signalr, silverlight-5.0, signalr.client

I'm working on a .NET 4.0/Silverlight 5.0 solution and I want to use SignalR to send push notifications from server to client.

I tried to install the latest version of the SignalR server (2.0.2) via Nuget but I get an error regarding Owin 2.0 (which obviously targets .NET 4.5 and is not compatible with .NET 4.0).

So I tried an older version (SignalR 1.2.0) but that one does not play along with the Silverlight client (0.5.0).

I get an exception that says "Incompatible protocol version" (without stating which version I'm using and which is excepted).

I couldn't find a list of server and Silverlight client packages that work together.

Can someone point me to the latest versions of a client for Silverlight 5.0 and a server package for .NET 4.0?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the .NET client - 2.0.2 http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/2.0.2
For the Server - 1.2.0 http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/1.2.0